# Read two floats with delimiting characters

Tags: c++, cin

I have to read a stdin entry using the istream operator.
I have to provide two entries as `(x1,y1)(x2,y2)` in one line.

```
cin >> a >> b;
```

This code internally (called complex.cpp) has this method overridden where we do this

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, complex& a) {
    char temp;
    float re, im;
    in >> temp >> re >> temp >> im >> temp;
    a.x = re;
    a.y = im;
    return in;
}
```

For some reason, It takes the first coordinates and messes up reading the second complex number.
To make thing really bad, I put a breakpoint at

```
in >> temp >> re >> temp >> im >> temp;
```

and that messes the stream. Help needed to be able read both coordinates.

Comment: I tried compiling this with g++ and it seems to work well. % g++ main.cpp complex.cpp
ComplexNumbersImplementation % ./a.out
Enter two complex numbers in the form (re, im): (2,4)(1,-1)
It seems that it has the right values

Comment: It won't work if you have any whitespace before the delimiter characters, because `>>temp` will read the space, not the delimiter. Then it won't be able to read the next number.

Comment: The I/O manipulator `std::ws` can absorb spaces. `char lparen, comma, rparen; if (in >> ws >> lparen >> re >> ws >> comma >> im >> ws >> rparen && lparen == '(' && rparen == ')' && comma == ',') { ... }` -- it's a bit grimey though.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I wonder if you getting into trouble because your code contains `using namespace std;`, and then creates a struct (or class) named `complex`. The Standard Library already has a class named `complex`, so that would be a recipe for trouble. Indeed, the Standard Library also provides overloads of `operator>>` for class `complex`. In any event, I suggest renaming your class `complex` to `Complex`.

Comment: Provide an example of the data in the file/stream that is being read from.   At a guess (since you haven't provided such a sample) an error is occurring reading at least one of the `float`s, which puts the stream in a bad state.   But to understand what is actually happening, other people (who experience an analogous set of errors when attempting to read your mind) need to know what data is actually being read.

Comment: In addition to @Paddy, FYI: [reading formatted input using C++ streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244655/7478597)